# Failed to load nodelet: Cannot load library: X: undefined symbol: Y

Tags: pcl, pcl-ros, nodelet, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm trying to rewrite the NormalEstimation (normal_3d) nodelet from pcl_ros to return PointNormal instead of just Normal. The code differs just in the point type and that I'm using pcl::concatenateFields to merge the PointXYZ and Normal cloud.

The compilation goes without problems but when I try to load the nodelet it produces the following error:

```
[ERROR] [1336114049.032926038]: Failed to load nodelet [/normal_estimation] of 
 type [clopema/NormalEstimationXYZ]: Failed to load library /home/wagnelib
 /ros_workspace/clopema/lib/libnormal_3d_xyz.so. Make sure that you are calling the  
 PLUGINLIB_REGISTER_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent 
 between this macro and your XML. Error string: Cannot load library: /home/wagnelib
 /ros_workspace/clopema/lib/libnormal_3d_xyz.so: undefined symbol: 
 _ZN7pcl_ros7Feature6onInitEv
[FATAL] [1336114049.037160798]: Service call failed!
```

---

### UPDATE 1:

I have found that the library libnormal_3d_xyz.so is not linked with libpcl_ros_feature.so and probably should, so the question is how to link this library?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33254/failed-to-load-nodelet:-cannot-load-library:-x:-undefined-symbol:-y/) by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 801 on 2012-05-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2014-04-27**:
What is the relation with libnormal_3d_xyz and libpcl_ros_feature.so? What I get that if if your libnormal_3d_xyz is using services of any other libraries, then you should link them up??? I am looking for an answer of the question posted here http://answers.ros.org/question/157886/error-while-loading-nodelet-velocity_multiplexer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer is actually simple, I just have to add:

```
target_link_libraries(normal_3d_xyz pcl_ros_features)
```

into `CMakeLists.txt` because the pcl_ros manifest doest include it by default.

---

Originally posted by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) with karma: 801 on 2012-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-03-29**:
No need to add header files to `include_directories`?